# SQL - Need some help for this situation without using cursor

Tags: sql, cursor

Currently, in my stored procedure, I'm using the Cursor for the situation below. What I know is we need to avoid using Cursors as much as we can.

So, I post the situation here to you can help me to solve it.

1. In table A, I use Cursor to get one-by-one UserID
2. With each UserID, I call 2 functions to work with business. The result is 2 strings.
3. These 2 strings will be saved to table B.
4. If success, do 2 actions: update Status = 1 in table A. And return a message.
5. If fail, do 1 action: return a message.
6. Loop Cursor

With business from step 2 - 5, how can we create a stored procedure with using the Cursor?

I hope you can give me advice to solve this.

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Sql Server?

Comment: what does "if success" mean in (4) ?

Comment: Please include the code that you are currently using.

Comment: Diego: yes, it's SQL server 2008.

Grisha: "if success" means those 2 strings saved into table B successfully.

Dems: I just want to have a solution to solve it if possible. In fact, my stored procedure is very long and complex.
Thanks all for your reply.

Comment: Well, from your pseudo-code it looks like you never use more than one iteration of your loop - steps 4-5 exit the loop in any case...

Answer (score 1):

Who says you need to avoid using cursors?
Cursors are provided for a reason, and there are some situations where you have to use a cursor or resort to fetching the records and processing the logic in some programming language.

If you want to have a per record success or failure, within the database even inside a stored procedure, you will need a cursor. (yes there are insert after triggers but that would just complicate your logic)

Comment: Currently, my table has around 10.000.000 records. If I use the cursors for business, this table will lock, and no one can does with it. So, I ask this question to looking some ways to solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on a high level you can do something like this (I added a insertDate in your table B because I think it would be necessary to the update)

First, insert data from tableA into tableB:

```
insert into tableB (ID, column1, column2, insertDate)
select ID, callFunction1(userID), callFunction2(userID), getdate()
```

then for the records inserted, set status=1

```
update tableA
set status=1 
where ID in (select ID from tableB where insertDate=today)
```

now, the return message kind is kinda complicated, you cant return a message per row, if any of them "fail", the whole batch will fail.

what exactly would cause a failure in your case?

Comment: yes, your solution is very helpful for me to reference. I will try to apply it in my stored procedure. 
Thank you for your help.